# Populating a TableView based off nearby posts from users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am trying tp pull all user posts from firebase to populate a TableView based off the posts locations relative to the current users locations.

I wrote a method to determine the distance between the user and the location of the posts stored in firebase.

*** I reworked the method to encapsulate all of the populating tableview data; however it is still not finding a value for "userLocation" ***

```
 func populateTableView() {

    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
     Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(userId!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] 
        let postLocation = data!["userLocation"] as? CLLocation //this is where it throws an error(found nil while unwrapping)
        let distanceFromPost: CLLocationDistance = self.locationManager.location!.distance(from: postLocation!)
        if self.metersInTwentyFiveMiles > distanceFromPost {
           self.inRangeOf = true
            Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    self.posts.removeAll()

                    for data in snapshot {
                        print(data)
                        if let postDict = data.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            let key = data.key
                            let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                            self.posts.append(post)
                            }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }, withCancel: nil)
            } else {
           self.inRangeOf = false
            print("no posts nearby")
            }
     })
    }
```

Now inside my viewDidLoad I just called the populateTableView function

```
   self.populateTableView()
```

I have numerous posts stored in firebase from the exact location of the simulator, its just not picking them up in the function.

The data in firebase is structured as:

```
-posts
 -L922cw8LC2fpxLI1zZH
  imageUrl: 
  likes: 
  userImg: 
  userLocation: 
  username:
```

Can anyone help me out? Could the populateTableView method not be reading from the right child node?

Comment: Your `isInRange` will take time to perform the asynchronous operation. Make sure you don't check `self.inRangeOf` until after it is actually set.

Comment: should I reload the tableView in the isInRange method?

Comment: That is probably what you want.

Comment: Still not getting results

Comment: Could I not be reading the data right off firebase?

Comment: @AustinBurger rmaddy was correct in the explanation that data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time `viewDidLoad` is invoked, the data won't have been loaded yet. If you updated your code to handle that, please update your question with the updated code.

Comment: I moved the tableview.reload into the isInRange method and then called the method from the view did load. after doing so I got this error message:Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1120d5850) to 'NSDictionary'

Comment: I fixed the last error (Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1120d5850) to 'NSDictionary') and edited the code in the post. it is saying that its finding 'nil' for userLocation. Is this because its not reading the right data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm understanding what you intend to do but as I understand it:

```
if self.metersInTwentyFiveMiles < distanceFromPost {
```

This should be

```
if self.metersInTwentyFiveMiles > distanceFromPost {
```

To be in Reach: Máximum distance > current distance

Comment: ... nice. That’s what no sleep does to you